# Javascript function works on html onclick but doesn't work html onload

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onload

I want to change the innerText of elements on my HTML after loading them.

```
<strong class="price" onclick="toPriceFormat(this)">2000</strong>
<strong class="price" onclick="toPriceFormat(this)">3000</strong>
<strong class="price" onclick="toPriceFormat(this)">1000</strong>
```

and I use this javascript function:

```
<script>
      function toPriceFormat(x) {
        let initText = parseInt(x.innerText);
        newTextFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(initText);
        x.innerText = newTextFormat;
      }
</script>
```

This `onclick` works but doesn't work `onload` event, for example I can't change my HTML to:

```
<strong class="price" onload="toPriceFormat(this)">2000</strong>
<strong class="price" onload="toPriceFormat(this)">3000</strong>
<strong class="price" onload="toPriceFormat(this)">1000</strong>
```

I want to know what's the different in functionality of `onclick` and `onload`

Comment: Does every element emit a `load` event? I don't think so. The window does, that's where you should hook it. Using inline JS like that is not a great way of writing code anyway. Include a `script` tag, select all your `.price` elements with `querySelectorAll` and then apply the `toPriceFormat` to those.

Comment: Supported HTML tags for HTML onload Event Attribute are: `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>` and `<style>`. See [Technical Details of HTML onload Event Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp).